# how set Image in jTable cell when click(Mouse Event) the row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon, renderer

How to set the Image in jTable cell when click(Mouse event) the row?If I select first row the image will display in that row.Then i click the second row, the image will show in the second row?how to do this using table cell renderer or prepare renderer?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the image to appear in the table cell, use the [default renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for `ImageIcon` and ensure that your `TableModel` returns `ImageIcon.class` for that column.

If you want the image to appear in response to a click, consider using a variation of [`TablePopupEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) with `setClickCountToStart(1)` and your image as an `Icon`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your 4th question on displaying an image in a JTable, so I'm guessing you already know how to do that.

So if you want to update a row when the selection changes then you will need to use a ListSelectionListener. Then when the listener fires you will need to update the TableModel to remove the icon from the previous row and update the icon in the current row.

[JList: previous selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191012/jlist-previous-selected-item/9197927#comment11582579_9197927) shows you you can get the row numbers to update.

Comment: Post your SSCCE demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this, is to make you own table cell renderer.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if(isSelected){
               return new Image(); // if selected
            }
return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); // if not selected do the normal stuff
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: return super(...); what will come in the super()?

Comment: super is to call the superclass or a method of the superclass. so you have to call the method you have overridden.

Comment: when i use like this ,the image will not appear in the JTable

Comment: you have to modify the code and not just copy it. you have say where the image is found and you need to load it. have a look at the ImageIO class of java.

Comment: oh sorry kleopatra is right. you have to place the image on a jLabel. an return th Jlabel

Comment: -1, there is not need to create a custom renderer. JTable supports a default renderer for displaying Icons. You just add the icon to the model and override the getColumnClass() method and the proper renderer will be used.